# Suddenly can't open any of my java programs in Intelliji

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

Everytime I attempt to click on my java applications nothing comes up:

[image]

I did not have this issue before. I was able to previously open my java class files and run the program with no issues.

Comment: it seems that google and intelliji pretty much messed up some things with last updates, what was the last thing you changed? (sdk / software updates, things like this)

Comment: Check the event-log of the IDE (bottom right corner). There should be a few error-messages that state what the problem is. Without that there isn't much to do here apart from closing the question. And since you're rather new here: please take some time to check the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and welcome to SO :)

Comment: Here is the messages I get when I click on the Event Log:"
"11:03 AM Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

11:03 AM Compilation completed successfully in 18s 960ms

11:05 AM Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

11:05 AM Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA

11:18 AM Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA
"

Comment: did you try to restart your computer? My android studio stopped working today for no (apparent) reason and suddenly worked again after reboot

Comment: yeah , that didn't work

Comment: no idea of what was changed for it to stop working?

Comment: Have you invalidated your caches?  Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and select "Invalidate Caches".

Comment: Nope ,unfortunately not

Comment: Thanks, Makoto, Ill try that

Comment: I have had this issue before, and (sometimes) re-importing the project from Github fixed it.

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: Happened twice for me now, and first time it couldn't even save the open .java file but screwed it up. Switching back to 2.3.3...

Answer (score 0):

Please close the current project and also exit IntelliJ IDEA (better to invalidate cache and restart)
Try to re-import the project.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the fault of the new update.

Three possible solutions could be either switching back to an older version until they have it fixed, or wait until they fix it, or try a different IDE for a little.